# Can I integrate Shibboleth SSO in my Java Webapp without using Apache and shibd?

Tags: java, jetty, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I'm working on a pure Java web application that uses an embedded Jetty and I want to integrate a Shibboleth login. To do this, I'm following [switch.ch's guide for Shibboleth Service Provider Deployment](https://www.switch.ch/aai/guides/sp/), which states:

> The Shibboleth Service Provider consists of a daemon shibd running on
>   all major operating systems and a web server module mod_shib which is
>   natively supported by:
>
> - Apache web servers (versions 1.3.x, 2.x)
> - IIS (versions 6, 7 and 8)

My question is, is there a way to integrate Shibboleth SSO in my Java web application without using an Apache web server or IIS running shibd? Maybe somebody has done this before and could provide example Servlets/Filters or the like?

I don't want an Webserver in front of the application just for Shibboleth, because it would complicate the installation. Currently, the installation is just two steps: extract the artefact and run the start script and I would appreciate if I could keep it like this.

Comment: From my experience, deploying the native Shibboleth SP with a web server in front of the Java AS is for the time being actually the easiest and most robust solution. Alternatively: a) use a Java-based solution such as [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org), [gluu](http://www.gluu.org) or [OIOSAML](http://digitaliser.dk/group/42063/resources) or b) go down the potentially painful path of writing up your own SP as a Java EE authentication component, with use of a low-level library such as [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home).

Answer (score 1):

The Shibboleth Service Provider takes care of a lot of complex use cases like key rotation, metadata refreshing, and attribute re-mapping. If you have an incredibly simple use case, where you need to authenticate users from one Shibboleth Identity Provider that rarely changes, you can consider validating the SAML 2.0 assertion in your Java code directly.

If you use spring-security already, you should probably start by looking at the spring-security-saml project:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

Alternatively, you can start with a low-level library like OpenSAML (https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home) or you can start with a higher level library like the LastPass Java SAML SDK (https://github.com/lastpass/saml-sdk-java).

Answer (score 1):

Putting shibboleth sp with web server in front is the easiest way out. Additionally you can add servlet filter and check header , if you find all attributes released by idp validate them against your identity store just for assertion.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by _validate them against your identity store just for assertion_. Could you elaborate on that? I understanding is, that the Apache Webserver, which is running on a different machine in my case, just adds headers to the http request. How could I, from within my Java Application Server, validate something? Where would I find the identity store and how to access it?

Comment: Identity store could be anything like AD or database. IDP must be validating the user against it. You can either access it or create a user info at SP side by syncing the users. Extract the user info from header and try to look up user in user store. You have to do it using a servlet filter inside your java web app.

Comment: I can't access the user database shibboleth is using. All I get from shib are a bunch of http headers: `givenName`, `surname`, `uniqueId` and so on. I use the `uniqueId` to create and link a user account.

Comment: Then you can just validate the header. If agreed header is present then you can assume the user is authenticated. Assume the idp is sending header with name my_id , in your servlet filter just if my_Id is there in header or not. If it's there use that as user id. In case you don't want to put a web server in front then you might have to use opensaml to parse the saml response and then do the header validation as I have mentioned above.