# Setting up shibboleth SP with Django

Tags: django, apache, authentication, shibboleth

I am a bit lost on where to start here.

Right now I'm am trying to create a shibboleth SP sign on to allow students from my university to use the Shibboleth IDP to access a service I am working on.

The stack now is Django backend with react front end and want to use Shibboleth's auth capabilities. As of now, I am having extreme difficulty finding where to start and how to actually implement a login with shibboleth.

I was able to get the configurations for the login (SP private key, SP cert, Metadata, Shibd config, Attribute Map),but yet, no idea where to start or apply these.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781579/any-java-application-for-shibboleth-authentication/22786142#22786142 java app. Might help.